# build installer electron app for windows on linux using electron-forge windows squirrel

Tags: linux, windows, electron, wine, electron-forge

how can we create installer for electron app for windows on linux (CentOS) using electron forge.

when i tried facing below issue

wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\tmp\acs-bot\node_modules\electron-winstaller\vendor\rcedit.exe.
at ChildProcess. (/tmp/acs-bot/node_modules/electron-winstaller/src/spawn-promise.ts:52:16)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
at Socket. (node:internal/child_process:458:11)
at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at Pipe. (node:net:301:12)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common request. It's hard to do cross-building with Forge/Builder but there is a different deployment tool that does it automatically without needing any setup (no wine etc). It might be useful for you:

https://hydraulic.dev/

(disclosure: I work on this tool)